# r: "gap"-index in function NbClust() works only with multivariate data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am using `NbClust()` to find the optimal number of clusters. My data contains only one variabale, i.e. one column. When I am executing

```
nc = NbClust(df,distance="euclidean", method="complete", index="alllong")
```

it produces the following error message

> Error in diag(var(Xuse)) : invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

When I tried all indices seperately I found out that the "gap"-index is responsible for causing this error. 
Therefore, I wonder, wether it is not possible to apply the "gap"-index to a one-dimensional dataframe? Because, when applied to a two-dimensional dataframe it works.